# MooTools - how to reload image?

Tags: image, camera, mootools, reload

Is there any way to reload the same image using mootools. I have a camera that gives me image, but I have to refresh it. I wrote this, but it doesn't work so well:

```
var url = "some valid url to some image.jpg";
var timer = 10; 
var periodical;

var camera_container;
var refresh = (function() {
    var loader = new Asset.image(url, {
        onLoad : function() {
            camera_container.empty();
            camera_container.inject(loader);
        }
    });
});

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // the periodical starts here, the * 1000 is because milliseconds required
    refresh.periodical(timer * 1000, this); 
    camera_container = $('camera-image');
});
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why not add a seeding bit to the url?

```
(function() {
    var url = "some valid url to some image.jpg?";
    this.timer = 10;
    var counter = 0;

    this.refresh = (function() {
        var loader = new Asset.image(url + counter, {
            onLoad: function() {
                camera_container.empty();
                camera_container.inject(loader);
                counter++;
            }
        });
    });

})();

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // the periodical starts here, the * 1000 is because milliseconds required
    refresh.periodical(timer * 1000, this);
    this.camera_container = $('camera-image');
});
```

this way the url will always be path/image.jpg?n where n changes and will force the browser to re-fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this also can work:

```
<div id="image-holder">
    <img src="http://www.image.com/image.jpg"/>
</div>


var srcImage   = 'http://www.image.com/image.jpg';
var reloadTime = 4000;
var holder = document.id('image-holder');

var imageReload = function(){
    holder.empty();
    var newImage =  new Element('img',{
            id:'image',
            src:srcImage ,
            alt:'image new'
        }).inject(holder);    
}

var start = function() {
    interval = imageReload.periodical(reloadTime);
};

start();
```